# What is the best Linux distro for software development, mainly C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking for the Linux distro that will fit me the best.
The OS will run on an old desktop with a 3.xGHz Intel Pentium 4 processor with 1 gig of ram, so no tremendous system. I plan to use it primarily for surfing the web (not games or anything) and develop software in primarily C. I want the OS to come with the entire GCC toolchain, or a package manager that makes it really easy to install (like APT).
And I don't want any visual effects or fancy desktop graphics or anything. I wouldn't mind it being simpler than Windows XP... or at least, it should be really easy to turn of all desktop effects and such.

Thanks,
Benjamin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use classic debian (squeeze) it is very lightweight and very stable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of opinion.
I know some people like Ubuntu, and think it has all you ask for. I'm sure other distributions aren't bad either.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu would be my choice. Lightweight enough to run on a computer with your specs, yet robust. Give that a shot.